# Bootstrap is not rendered in Scala Play framework

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have included Bootstrap into my Scala/Play Project in Intellij. 
But it is not rendering.

I included bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js and jquery-3.4.1.min.js.

Folder structure:

in public folder: Folder css with bootstrap.min.css and main.css; Folder images with favicon.img; Folder js with bootstrap.min.js, jquery-3.4.1.min.js and main.js

HTML-Codes where I am trying to access bootstrap

in the HTML header

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href=@routes.Assets.versioned("css/main.css")">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href=@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Before the closing body-tag:

```html
<script src=@routes.Assets.versioned("js/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=@routes.Assets.versioned("js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src=@routes.Assets.versioned("js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The result is a HTML page without any css (Default font: Times new Roman).
The HTML page is not rendered using bootstrap.

How I can include Bootstrap so that it is rendered correctly?

Comment: do you have any errors in console or css asset not loaded? check network tab for css file. sounds like problem with your host resolving the url. often a problem with setup of apache or nginx. what kind of server are you using?

Comment: In Firefox I found the error message: "The ressource from "http://localhost:9000/css/bootstrap.min.css" was blocked due to MIME type conflict". I am developing with IntelliJ and I am using sbt run to run the application. What can I do to solve this issue?